# Give error if there is no network connection when attempting to save file to isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, internet-connection, network-connection

I'd like to give the user an error message and prevent app from crashing, if they do not have a network connection when attempting to save a file to the isolatestorage.  What I have does not give me an error when building, but crashes when I attempt to save a file.

```
 private void LongListSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LongListSelector selector = sender as LongListSelector;

        // verifying our sender is actually a LongListSelector
        if (selector == null)
            return;

        SoundData data = selector.SelectedItem as SoundData;

        // verifying our sender is actually SoundData
        if (data == null)
            return;


        if (data.IsDownloaded)
        {
            if (audioStream != null)
            {
                audioStream.Close();
                audioStream.Dispose();
            }

            audioStream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().OpenFile(data.SavePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

            AudioPlayer.SetSource(audioStream);
            AudioPlayer.Play();

        }
        else
        {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.OpenReadCompleted += (senderClient, args) =>
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().CreateFile(data.SavePath))
                {
                    if (args == null || args.Cancelled || args.Error != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please check your network/cellular connection. If you have a network connection, verify that you can reach drobox.com");
                        return;
                    }

                    args.Result.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    args.Result.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    AudioPlayer.SetSource(fileStream);
                    AudioPlayer.Play();


                }
            };
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(data.FilePath));

        }
```

Comment: how about `try{} catch`?

Comment: To get the exception?  Judging by the code, are you under the impression that it should work or does it look incorrect?

Comment: Shouldn't you check for networking availability inside the event handler. From your code it looks like it's checked when class instance is created. The state of the network availability can be different at the time of class creation and when the `OpenReadCompleted` event is triggered.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski Ive tried moving it before the Webclient even starts. But that doesn't work either. If I run it in the emulator and turn off the Network, it always errors at `args.Result.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`                             The exception is basically its not finding it on the server. So its never checking for a network connection.

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski   Also, Id like to put it in a place where it doesn't always check for a Network connection. Only when the app has to look to the server for the file if its not already in isolated storage.

Comment: What I meant was to use this `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();` inside your `if` check. So instead of using this if clause: `if (isNetworkAvailable == false)` replace it with that one: `if(!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())`

Comment: Ok.  Changed it. Same exception at the first args.. line still occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try checking the parameter before attempting to use it?

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().CreateFile(data.SavePath))
{                    
    if (args == null || args.Cancelled || args.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No connection");
        return;
    }

    args.Result.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    args.Result.CopyTo(fileStream);
    AudioPlayer.SetSource(fileStream);
    AudioPlayer.Play();
}
```

or like user574632 said, wrap the entire thing in a try/catch. This will allow it to fail gracefully so the user will see whatever error you put in the catch block without crashing the entire application.

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe Ill try the try/catch. Your solution works, except that if the user gets the connection back during the same section, the particular files they previously tried when there was no connection, still wont work. THey would have to close out the app and start it again.

Comment: Well regardless if you put it into a try/catch, you're going to run into the same problem unless you tie the code to initialize/connect to the resource to the user interface. You could put the code into some sort of button to allow the user to retry the connection.

Comment: Yep. You're right. Does the same thing. Tricky. Ill stay with one of these options for now.  Not the best solution but ill also look into a retry connection button of some sort. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the button thing will work. This app has buttons with sounds that are populated automatically from a Viewmodel. I am surprised the network connection check doesn't work right in this instance.

Comment: I've edited the code above to include more of the mainpage.cs The LongListSelector portion is the most relevant to the start of loading/checking data. I have the project on GitHub also if youd like to see more of it.